# Convert any address to accountId (in hex)

Tags: polkadot-js, cryptography, scale, ss58format

How can i convert an address of the form `"5DTNtGF2DmZ7QwGxg6n1xWzF6cEokNyNre7mUqpVuozrLxu3"` to hex **using polkadotjs packages**?

Here is the context:

I have multiples array of datas, containing `address: balance`.
I have to make interactions between these data (like searching the balance of the specific address). The problem is that, between array, the format is different (addresses start by 3, sometime by 5, sometimes are in hex...) so i cannot compare anything as the format is different.

So i'd like to convert everything back to a hex account id, where everything will correspond.

I'v found a way to change the prefix, decode into array of 32 int, but i couldnt find a way to convert to hex...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a couple of options.

First, if you already have an initialized API in your app -

```js
const ADDR = "5DTNtGF2DmZ7QwGxg6n1xWzF6cEokNyNre7mUqpVuozrLxu3"

// create a type from this
const id = api.registry.createType("AccountId", ADDR)

// convert to hex
const hex = id.toHex()

// alternatively, you can just compare directly to 
// something else that can be an ss58 address, hex
// or even Uint8Array (raw decoded bytes are compared)
const isEqual = id.eq("SomethingElse")
```

Your second option is via the `decodeAddress` -

```js
import { u8aToHex } from "@polkadot/util"
import { decodeAddress } from "@polkadot/util-crypto"

const ADDR = "5DTNtGF2DmZ7QwGxg6n1xWzF6cEokNyNre7mUqpVuozrLxu3"

// convert to hex
const hex = u8aToHex(decodeAddress(ADDR))

// test for equality
const isEqual = hex === "0xdeadbeef"
```

Option 3 - if the array is from the API, you can use the first option and just use the `.eq` directly on it (without creating)

Comment: Thanks a lot !
And by curiosity, did you find this on documentation ?

Comment: For the first option - all Codec objects have `.toHex()` and `.eq()` on them that will convert and compare, so that is standard to all API-returned objects. For the second option, it is just a variation of https://polkadot.js.org/docs/util-crypto/examples/validate-address

Comment: ooooh ok, thanks again !

Answer (score 1):

There is also the `/accounts/{address}/validate` endpoint in [Sidecar](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-api-sidecar) which takes a ss58 or hex (from a u8 array) formatted address and returns the following information :

- isValid
- ss58Prefix
- network
- **accountId**

You can find more info regarding this endpoint :

- in [Sidecar docs](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate-api-sidecar/dist/)
- in the latest [PR](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-api-sidecar/pull/926) where the `accountId` was added
- in the corresponding function `validateAddress` in [sidecar code](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-api-sidecar/blob/2a3702e2b9b21228dbb949d0f0dd71cd878c4fc6/src/services/accounts/AccountsValidateService.ts#L38) (`src/services/accounts/AccountsValidateService.ts`)

Answer (score 0):

https://www.shawntabrizi.com/substrate-js-utilities/

Source: https://github.com/shawntabrizi/substrate-js-utilities

```
import { u8aToHex } from "@polkadot/util";

/* AccountId to Hex */
let a2h = {
    "account": document.getElementById("account-a2h"),
    "hex": document.getElementById("hex-a2h")
};

a2h.account.addEventListener("input", account2hex);
a2h.hex.addEventListener("input", hex2account);

function account2hex() {
    try {
        a2h.hex.value = u8aToHex(decodeAddress(a2h.account.value));
    } catch (e) {
        a2h.hex.value = "Error";
        console.error(e);
    }
}

function hex2account() {
    try {
        a2h.account.value = encodeAddress(a2h.hex.value);
    } catch (e) {
        a2h.account.value = "Error";
        console.error(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: See this issue for more formal specs to be re-added to some docs soon https://github.com/paritytech/ss58-registry/issues/112

Comment: As i said in my question, i'll need a solution from polkadotjs package. I imagine that ``u8aToHex`` comes from polkadotjs, if yes, it was exactly the function i was searching for. But from which package ? api ? util-crypto ?